# Restriction in HQL with Date

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a class auction like

```
public class Auction  extends LightEntity implements IsSerializable 
{
   private long AuctionId;
   private Date StartTime;
   private Date EndTime;
}
```

i need to perform write an hql using restriction which chooses all auction whose end time has not yet completed.

my xml mapping file for the auction class is

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Auction" table="AUCTION">
        <id name="AuctionId" type="long">
            <column name="AUCTIONID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="StartTime" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="STARTTIME" />
        </property>
        <property name="EndTime" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="ENDTIME" />
        </property>
..
.
.
.
>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely respect the Java naming conventions : variables and fields start with a lower-case letter in Java (auctionId, startTime, endTime).

Now your question : 
either you compute the current time, and pass it as a parameter to your query :

```
Date now = new Date();
Query q = session.createQuery("select a from Auction a where a.endTime > :now");
q.setTimeStamp("now", now);
return q.list();
```

or you use [expressions supported by HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) :

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select a from Auction a where a.endTime > current_timestamp()");
return q.list();
```